# Do I need to re-link the database again to make sure tables which are linked in Access also gets updated?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2010

I am new into MS access. Earlier, I have linked the tables in MS access 2010 through SQL server. Now, today I replaced the existing database and restored updated backup file of same database.

My Questions is, do I need to re-link the database again to make sure tables which are linked in Access also gets updated?

Note: I have refreshed the linked tables in access.

Comment: Please do let me know if need more clarity..

Answer (score 1):

If the table structure in the backup is 100% identical to the originally linked tables, you don't need to do anything.
The data is retrieved "live" from the server.

If there are differences, you need to re-link the tables, or run `TableDef.RefreshLink` for each linked table.
The table structure is only retrieved when linking the table, Access doesn't automatically retrieve changes in the structure (e.g. added columns).